# Bootstrap is not working on my code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It looks like I miss some stupid bug, but I checked the code many times: looks like everything done in acording to the docs. I downloaded the latest (3.0.3) bootstrap version one more time... But the page looks plain (with no Bootstrap styling):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Page title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <a href='#' class='btn'>Скачать</a><br />
    <div class="pagination">
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>4</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>5</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>6</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>7</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone point me to my mistake?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle please?

Comment: Are you sure you're including the right path? Go to your browser's console and check whether your files load or not.

Comment: Have checked with your browsers inspector? On where the stylesheet __href="templates/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"__
points at?

Comment: Forget to indicate that the Chrome's console show no errors. So the paths are right. I will provide you with jsfiddle soon!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J3h43/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to documentation of Bootstrap 3, you have to put `btn-default` along with the `btn` class.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

So your code would rather be `<a href='#' class='btn btn-default'>Скачать</a>`

Regarding to pagination, you have got to put `class="pagination"` to `ul` not its parent div.

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href='#'>1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>5</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>6</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>7</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>8</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the viewport meta tag if you want a responsive layout:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Also, if you're using the default download, you also need to include the theme CSS file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/the/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
```

Comment: Adding the bootstrap-theme.min.css file changed a bit the view of the button. But no change to pagination section.
The adding of mention above <meta> tag changed nothing

Comment: @RomanMatveev The meta tag only becomes useful if your site will be viewed at different resolutions. If you have the Web Developer Toolbar (for Firefox or Chrome), load the site and then go to Resize > View Responsive Layouts; you'll see different behavior with & without the meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li><a href='#'>1</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>2</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>3</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>4</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>5</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>6</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>7</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>8</a></li>
```

is wrong

it must be

```
<ul class="pagination">
```

«

1

2

3

4

5

»

the href must be "" and not ''

Comment: I should disagree with you. Both types of quotes are available. Here is the citation from w3schools.com:
'Double style quotes are the most common, but single style quotes are also allowed.'
The citation taken from http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp